# How to do aggregation in Spark Streaming without watermarking?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, delta-live-tables

Let's assume I have a streaming data set like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|package_id| timestamp             | values    |
|----------|-----------------------|-----------|
|  1       |  2023-01-01 00:00:00  | [1,2,3]   |
|  2       |  2023-01-01 00:00:10  | [4,5,6]   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I explode the values column:

```
--------------------------------------------
|package_id| timestamp             | value |
|----------|-----------------------|-------|
|  1       |  2023-01-01 00:00:00  | 1     |
|  1       |  2023-01-01 00:00:00  | 2     |
|  1       |  2023-01-01 00:00:00  | 3     |
|  2       |  2023-01-01 00:00:10  | 4     |
|  2       |  2023-01-01 00:00:10  | 5     |
|  2       |  2023-01-01 00:00:10  | 6     |
--------------------------------------------
```

Now, let's say I want to **undo** the explode, and return the data to its original state (I know it doesn't make sense, I am just trying to simplify my use case). To accomplish that, I need to do a groupby-aggregate operation. But Spark Streaming says that to be able to apply aggregates, I need to use watermarking. I don't need to care about late arriving data, because even though packages may arrive late, I already have the complete data for each package. And I don't want to use watermark just to satisfy Spark Streaming. Is there a way to accomplish this without using watermark?

**Additional notes:**

- I can't use forEachBatch, because I am using Databricks' Delta Live Tables and AFAIK forEachBatch is not available for it
- Why I don't want to use watermark?

  - I am not very familiar with the concept and find it a bit confusing
  - I'm worried that if I misconfigure it, I might unintentionally ignore some data